# How can I remove a key in cache? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.3

If I run:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r(Cache('test'));echo '</pre>';die();
```

the result is like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42
            [name] => real madrid
            [description] => ronaldo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [name] => chelsea
            [description] => hazard
        )

)
```

I want to remove the key that has the `id` = 42.

I try like this :

```
$id = 42;
foreach (Cache('test') as $key => $value) {
      if($key['id'] == $id) {
           Cache::forget($key);
      }
}
```

Then, I run:

```
dd(Cache('test'));
```

But the key with `id` = 42 is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry in cache is called `test`, and it is an array with multiple elements; so trying to delete an entry from cache with the id value `42` won't work because entry 42 isn't the cache entry, just a part of the array.

```
$ttl = 240;

$id = 42;
// retrieve the array from Cache
$value = Cache::get('test');
// Identify the entry with id of 42
$entry = array_flip(array_column($value, 'id'));
// delete that entry from the array
unset($value[$entry[$id]]);
// restore the modified array to cache
Cache::put('test', $value, $ttl)
```

Comment: When I run : `dd(Cache('test'));`, there is still exist key with id = 42. Seems, `Cache::put('test', $value)` does not work in laravel 5.3

Comment: [Laravel docs for Cache::put()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache).... check that the `$value` is being correctly modified to remove that entry

Comment: When I run : `dd($value);`, it remove the key that has the id = 42. But When I run : `dd(Cache('test'));`, there is still exist key with id = 42

Comment: Then is `Cache::put()` returning any error or status? I'm not running 5.3, but it looks as though a 3rd ttl argument is now mandatory, so try `Cache::put('test', $value, 240);`

Comment: When I run : `Cache::put('test', $value, 240);`, it works. Thanks

Comment: In my case, I ran into incorrect value store in cache, bcox multiple threads accessing the and modifying the value at the same time... 
How I solve this issue in MySQL is using similar logic like: 'update wallets set balance = balance - 0.5 where id=22;'
But i'm still looking for similar solution in Cache